# How to store directory, sub directory and file paths in a Python Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dictionary

I am developing a software which analyze excel files stored in Years directories which contains months directories and each month directory consist of excel files. Structure as shown below.
[image]

In order to achieve my goal, I have used the code below

```
os.walk("..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports")
```

the above code shows all the directories, sub directories and files

> ('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports', ['2022', '2023'], [])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022', ['1', '10', '11', '12', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], [])
> ('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\1', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\10', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\11', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\12', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\2', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\3', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\4', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\5', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\6', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\7', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\8', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2022\9', [], ['Basic Facilities.csv'])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2023', ['1'], [])('..\..\..\..\ema_monthly_reports\2023\1', [], ['Basic Facilities.xlsx'])

but I don't know how to properly manage years, months and files names in dictionary format.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can store this in a dictionary format would be to store them as nested dictionary. Something like the following:

```
directories = {"ema_monthly_reports":
    {"2022":
        {"1":"Basic Facilities.csv"},
        {"2":"Basic Facilities.csv"},
        ...
    },
    {"2023":
        {"1":"Basic Facilities.csv"},
        {"2":"Basic Facilities.csv"},
        ...
    }
}
```

In order to store values in this format. I think it is better to use `os.listdir()` and then write a recursive function like so:

```py
import os

def dir_as_dict(path, sep="/"):
    dictdir = {}

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        return None
    
    subdirs = os.listdir(path)

    for subdir in subdirs:
        #function runs recursively
        dictdir[subdir] = dir_as_dict(path+sep+subdir)
    
    return dictdir
```

Keep in mind that with this approach, files will be listed as a key that gives out the value `None`, which is necessary to make the recursive call work (since one directory can have both files and subdirectories).

My test output

```py
>>> dir_as_dict("./test")
{'2022': {'1': {'report.txt': None}, '2': {'report.txt': None}, '3': {'report.txt': None, 'report2.txt': None}, '4': {}}, '2023': {'1': {'report.txt': None}, '2': {'report.txt': None}, '3': {'report.txt': None, 'report2.txt': None}, '4': {}}}
```